# VBA Excel IE click button

Tags: vba, excel

How do I press this button with VBA Excel. It is a webpage that triggers a AJAX and then supplies a dropdown meny that I need to press in next. Just can not remember how I do this.

`<input type="button" 
name="ctl00$MainContent$m_Access$grdUserAccess$ctl00$ctl02$ctl02$Filter_CustomerName" 
value=" " 
onclick="$find(&quot;ctl00_MainContent_m_Access_grdUserAccess&quot;)._showFilterMenu(&quot;ctl00_MainContent_m_Access_grdUserAccess_ctl00&quot;, &quot;CustomerName&quot;, event); return false;__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$m_Access$grdUserAccess$ctl00$ctl02$ctl02$Filter_CustomerName','')"
 id="ctl00_MainContent_m_Access_grdUserAccess_ctl00_ctl02_ctl02_Filter_CustomerName" 
title="Filter" class="rgFilter">`

I have done it once but lost the code, because of a hard-crash. Right now I am at...

```
Dim form2 As Variant

Set form2 = ie.document.getelementsbyname("ctl00$MainContent$m_Access$grdUserAccess$ctl00$ctl02$ctl02$Filter_CustomerName")
form2.Click
```

But nothing happens.

Any tip will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set form2 = ie.document.getElementById( _ 
          "ctl00_MainContent_m_Access_grdUserAccess_ctl00_ctl02_ctl02_Filter_CustomerName")
form2.Click
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do 
Set form2 = ie.document.getElementById( _ 
          "ctl00_MainContent_m_Access_grdUserAccess_ctl00_ctl02_ctl02_Filter_CustomerName")
form2.FireEvent("OnClick")